# SSH to a remote station without port forwarding on my mac

Tags: ssh

I would like to SSH onto a remote linux computer from the internet at school, which does not support port forwarding.

I type `ssh root@<myipadresshere.com`

but of course it fails.

Is there a way to SSH to my remote server using any network I am connected to without the ports being forwarded?

If I type SSH -A root@MyIP , it times out.

```
Skylers-MacBook-Pro:~ skylerfennell$ ssh -vvv root@kd0whb.duckdns.org
OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8y 5 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to kd0whb.duckdns.org [67.166.55.176] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/skylerfennell/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/skylerfennell/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/skylerfennell/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/skylerfennell/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_4.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_4.3 pat OpenSSH_4*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "kd0whb.duckdns.org" from file "/Users/skylerfennell/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /Users/skylerfennell/.ssh/known_hosts:6
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
Write failed: Broken pipe


Skylers-MacBook-Pro:~ skylerfennell$ ssh -a root@kd0whb.duckdns.org
    ssh: connect to host kd0whb.duckdns.org port 22: Operation timed out
```

Comment: Note that options can be implied by `/etc/ssh_config` and `~/.ssh/config` -- have you checked those files to make sure the type of forwarding you're explicitly trying not to do isn't enabled by default? See: http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config

Answer (score 1):

are you referring to port forwarding or agent forwarding?  By default, port forwarding isn't enabled unless you use -L or -R options.

Agent forwarding (for authentication using keys in your local ssh-agent) can be enabled by using

```
ssh -A <user>@<host>
```

Let me know if this is helpful.

Comment: Ok, well I won't be able to tell you until Monday

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: Nope, it timed out.

Comment: I think the network is restricting outgoing on 22

Comment: Try with -vvv and post the debug output so we can diagnose.

Comment: OK I edited the question with my result of -VVV

Comment: I don't see any of the output, try again?

Comment: oops i don't know why that didn't work Ok i edited it again.